# CPU 100% used by lockgit

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, gitaly

[image: top showing lockgit using 349.2% CPU]

How should I investigate this situation?

I have not killed it because I don't know if there will be other problems.

**I restarted `gitlab` but it didn't work.**

```
$ kill 3725346
```

[image]

kill has no effect on it, it seems to restart automatically.

try remove

I want to find the lockgit folder location and delete it.

```
$ cd /proc/185258ll
$ ll
```

[image]

I can't find the folder

Comment: "Lockgit" is not part of Git. it appears to be part of Gitaly, whatever that may be. It might be included with GitLab; I've added that tag to get GitLab experts to see this.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$ kill 3725346
```

and if need be, `kill -9`.

Prior to that you might wish to investigate
with `ps lp 3725346` to learn about its parent,
and `sudo lsof -p 3725346` to see what files
it has open. The `lsof` utility can also help
you find other processes which are holding open
a file of interest.

Certainly a resident set of > 2 GiB
is impressive.
Note whether this, or a subsequently
restarted git command, allocates that
immediately or if the memory footprint
slowly grows with time.

EDIT

The pkg source code is at
https://github.com/jswidler/lockgit .

Figure out how it is being invoked,
both command line args and environment.

Compile it with debug symbols.
Invoke under gdb (or `attach` gdb
to the running, spinning process).
Set a breakpoint at main(),
then single step through it until
things fall apart, same as you'd
debug any of your own programs
that went astray.

---

In an extreme case, you could arrange
for the problematic code to not run at all.
For example, chdir to its directory and
then `cp -p /usr/bin/true lockgit` .
It will immediately succeed, with no
effect. Which is Bad if you needed it
to properly manipulate some secrets,
but Good if you just want to move on
without the useless spinning process.

This might give you a better understanding of what's happening.
If it doesn't, then bite the bullet
and uninstall lockgit, stop using
a program once you find you cannot
make it run reliably in your environment.

Comment: I wrote lockgit for personal reasons to encrypt small config files.  I couldn't have given better advice than J_H.

Someone created a GitHub Issue on my repo and I followed up there with more details. But, if the reason this problem is occurring is because the original user is trying to access something he doesn't have a valid key for...

Comment: Given that https://github.com/jswidler/lockgit/issues/16 lacks sufficient detail for anyone to investigate it, I recommend closing it out with "cannot reproduce".

Comment: There's no instructions for how to repeat the bug on another laptop. This SO question needs debugging details for it to be helpful. Best to just close it.